# Run laravel project in a directory folder on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5, webserver

> **My question is:** How can i run a laravel application in a directory
>   (not in root) on a shared webhosting?

For some of my clients I run Laravel applications in the root folder of their selected shared webhosting and remove the **/public** part from the URL. To make this work i move the index.php to the root folder and change the information from the index.php to:

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Now i know that this can cause security problems but I already have found solutions to that case for shared webhosters.

> **The .htaccess i use to make this change is:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.eot|\.woff|\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

But in this case i want the laravel project to  be run in a directory called test.

> **Folder structure:**

```
root (public_html)
  |-- test (directory with laravel project)
```

Now I'm not sure if i can simply change the .htaccess as i'm not very skilled with .htaccess files. What changes do i have to make, to make this work?

> **Note my urls:**

```
// this link will be changed to:
    www.[text-placeholder].com/test/public/css/style.css 

// Output above result now:
    www.[text-placeholder].com/public/css/style.css

// But should be:
    www.[text-placeholder].com/test/public/css/style.css
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, just place the project 1 level above the public_html folder and rename the public folder itself to public_html.

[image]

P.S. This is maybe a better way, than to use .htaccess, because now you really know fore sure the files outside of public html are out of your webroot (not accessible by hackers) and with htaccess you can make a mistake and the files are exposed.

Comment: Isn't working for me: www.[text-placeholder].com/test/public/css/style.css still got changed to: www.[text-placeholder].com/public/css/style.css

Comment: you have to rename them locally and run `php artisan optimize` (`composer update`) first. The upload it to the shared hosting. I do it myself on vimexx.nl hosting. They use directadmin.

Comment: Did a quick workaround for this problem. Was able to make a subdomain like this: test.[text-placeholder].com. Now all files were linked correctly like usual.